# File upload at google apps script

Tags: file-upload, google-apps-script

I would like to add a fileupload to my Google Apps Script App.
In my Server Handler I just call my function like this:

```
    function serverHandler(params){
      uploadFile(params);
    ....
```

and the function looks like this:

```
    function uploadFile(e){ 
      var fileBlob = e.parameter.upload;
      var adoc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
      return adoc.getUrl();
    }
```

I always get the error: "Error encountered: Method createFile( not found and i have no clue how to solve it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: DocsList was deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot upload a file using a server handler. You should necessarily be doing a POST from a form Submit button.

See the nice example code in the [FileUpload widget documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_fileupload)

Comment: The linked class was deprecated.